# segmentation fault in subtracting Linked List elements

Tags: c, linked-list

I m trying to subtract two consecutive nodes and put the result in a new node before them.
But i am getting segmentation fault and then program stops responding.

here `LinkList` is a structure.

```
void subtract_node(LinkList **p)
{
    LinkList *q,*temp=NULL,*r;
    int i=0;
    q=r=*p;
    temp=(LinkList*)malloc(sizeof(LinkList));
    while(q!=NULL)
    {
        temp->item=q->next->item-q->item;
        temp->next=q;
        if(i==0)
        {
            *p=r=temp;
            r=r->next->next;
            q=q->next->next;
        }
        else
        {
            r->next=temp;
            temp=r;
            r=r->next->next;
            q=q->next->next;
        }
        printf("%d",i++);
    }
}
```

Comment: Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, and then construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).

Comment: You could give us the structure-definition itself instead of writing `here LinkList is a structure.`

Comment: What do you think happens at the end of your algorithm when your list has an odd number of nodes in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot dereference the `next` pointer in a linked list without null-checking its content first. Specifically, this expression

```
q->next->item - q->item
```

will fail when `q->next` is `NULL`. You did check `q` for `NULL` in the header of the loop, but you also need to check `q->next` to avoid the crash:

```
while((q!=NULL) && (q->next != NULL)) {
    ...
}
```